# Matlab convert struct to cell array of strings

Tags: matlab

I want to convert a structure to a cell array where all the entries are converted to strings, including numbers. If I take the MATLAB example:

```
s = 
    category: 'tree'
      height: 37.4000
        name: 'birch'
```

I want to convert this to

```
c = 
    'tree'
    '37.4000'
    'birch'
```

where all entries are converted to strings, including numbers. The function struct2cell(s) will convert s to:

```
ans =
    'tree'
    [37.4000]
    'birch'
```

Is there a quick way of getting from s to c?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to force everything to a string, you can use `num2str` with `cellfun`:

```
cellfun(@num2str, struct2cell(a), 'UniformOutput', false)
```

The result will be a cell array of strings.